# How we can jump to address of function(or specific address)?

Tags: stm32, c, arm, cortex-m, cortex-m4

I working with ARM CORTEX-M4. I wrote this code for jump to a function. I define this function:

```
void Shared_Func(void)
{
  while(1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port, LED_Pin);
    HAL_Delay(700);
  }
 }  
typedef void (*ptr_shared_func_t)(void);
ptr_shared_func_t ptr_shared_func;
```

and in main:

```
ptr_shared_func = Shared_Func;
ptr_shared_func();
```

if i run this code, it works and there is no problem. Then on debug mode i find address of Shared_Func and instead of use name of function i write:

```
unsigned int *add_shared_fun = (unsigned int *)0x08001055;// correct address is   0x08001054 ->for thumb2 change to 0x08001055
ptr_shared_func = (void(*)(void))(add_shared_fun);//Shared_Func;
```

in this case code not work! Now my question is whats the best solution and whats the problem in my code?

Comment: Impossible to tell what "it does not work" means. You need to be more precise in what goes wrong. You have a debugger, so use it!

Comment: It seems you make changes (and compile it again) between two tests. The address of the function probably changes too. You probably need some linker-scripting and give the function a hard-coded address.

Comment: @Tagli i checked address in debuger runtime and its not changed!

Comment: @HwSwDesigner So since you have a debugger, why haven't you debugged what happens then when you execute that code? Stepping through each assembly instruction will reveal why it does not work.

Comment: @Justme when i debug code i realized that compiler delete 'Shared_Func' beacause its not used explicitly, but even when i turn of all optimization(Level 0 in keil uvision v5.22) still 'Shared_Func' will delete!! only way i found for solve problem, use 'Shared_Func' in dummy instruction!!

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott because i want to use one function in bootloader program and then access it in application program without redefine the function(bootloader and application program are seperate projects).

Comment: In the bootloader you should have a jump table at a defined address. The jump table will have a reference to your function and the linker should not remove it. Nevertheless, there should be some method of telling the compiler/linker not to remove the function.  Time to read the documentation!